# I have Genymotion and Android Studio. I'm trying to consume service but getting error

Tags: android, genymotion

When debugging/ running my project I'm getting this error got this error:

```
10-22 05:19:08.252    3260-3260/com.example.myapp E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache   
10-22 05:19:08.252    3260-3260/com.example.myapp E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192    
10-22 05:19:08.272    3260-3260/com.example.myapp E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints() 
10-22 05:19:08.272    3260-3260/com.example.myapp E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 8192
```

Comment: Please provide more details than just the error message

Answer (score 0):

I use too Genymotion under Android Studio and I don't think is that an error, but is weird log produced by OpenGLRenderer. Genymotion VM by default has enabled Hardware OpenGL. You can read from this log, that app fetch maximum texture size from GradienCache and Caches::initConstraints(). You propably see that app work just like you want. For me looks like bad Log type only.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Neelsg and Hubix for your response.

I faced this issue and finally I got the reason for this, actually we have to use separate thread to consume service or use AsyncTask<>. 
The reason behind this issue is that we did lot of tasks in a single thread.

Comment: i am using separate thread for consuming webservices via handler and bean to retrieve data but using asyntask in same class. do i need to make a separate class for asynctask as well.